# Detect when link element loads and the href changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement theming on a web application. Currently there are several themes and a panel from which the user can change the theme.
I want to register an event and detect when the theme loads.
The code is as follows:

```js
const link = document.createElement('link')
link.rel = 'stylesheet'
link.href="first-theme.css'
link.onload = () => console.log('Theme loaded')

document.head.append(link)
```

This works fine when the first theme is set and the link element is created.

However, the problem is when I try to change the theme.
When I change the theme, I don't create a new link element, but rather update the href of the existing one.

```js
function changeTheme(theme){
  link.href=theme
}
```

When I call `changeTheme`, the `onload` event is not fired again, even though the new file is loaded.

As a side note, this workflow works on the img tag

```js
const img = document.createElement('img')
img.src='https://picsum.photos/200'
img.onload = () => console.log("Image loaded")

document.body.append(img)

setTimeout(() => img.src='https://picsum.photos/300', 1000)
setTimeout(() => img.src='https://picsum.photos/400', 2000)
```

The above code will print `Image loaded` for 3 times.

Comment: _"When I change the theme, I don't create a new link element, but rather update the href of the existing one"_ - so don't do that then, but _do_ create a new link element, same as you did before. Remove the existing one, to avoid any overlaps.

Comment: @CBroe, perhaps this is the solution I'll try. 
However, the fact that it doesn't work seems like a limitation of the browser, as this works fine for the `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I have never found a fix for this, I can suggest a workaround.

Place an empty `div` element off screen and have each CSS file set it to a different size. You can then use the [ResizerObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to detect when this element changes size as a proxy for the new stylesheet loading.

Comment: Yes, this is another good idea. We can even use CSS variables and on `body` tag to set a variable with the theme name and use the Web API to watch for changes. Thnx for suggestion. 
However, it's too hacky as we have multiple themes and setting this in every file will be out of scope, as new themes can be created all the time and this hack is error prone for our scenario.

Comment: You could have a simple server side script that injects the theme name variable in to the CSS file, ether when it is requested by the browser or as a build step, to eliminate the risk of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the theme using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and create a new `CSSStyleSheet` using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/replace) method:

```js
// response from fetch request
const textContent= "body { font-size: 1.4em; } p { color: red; }";

const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
stylesheet
  .replace(textContent)
  .then(() => {
     document.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet];
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Failed to replace styles:", err);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution I chose in the end was to create a new link element and remove the old one when the new one has finished loading.